# How to call BProlog goal from a C program?

Tags: prolog, b-prolog

The documentation of BProlog mentions:
"B-Prolog has a bi-directional interface with C through which Prolog programs
can call functions written in C and C programs can call Prolog as well. C pro-
grams that use this interface must include the file "bprolog.h" in the directory
$BPDIR/Emulator."
I can't find bprolog.h, nor a library to link against. Are these files only available with individual licences ?

Comment: It sounds like "bprolog.h" is only available in paid versions.  You might send an e-mail to support and ask "pretty please": support@probp.com

Answer (score 0):

You shoudl have in folder with your prolog, try find floder called 'include' perhaps

Comment: I don't think the object and header files are available for free. They are definitely not in the default install.

Comment: i dont know what licens you have academic? Then ask your academic teacher

Comment: There is no teacher or student involved. It's for my personal use with the free version available.